# Max ID join sql

Tags: sql, join, max

I have three sql tables,

1) Commandes, 2) Ligne_commande, 3) Produits.

commandes is linked with ligne_commande and ligne_commande is linked to produits.

```
Commandes : CMD_ID
Produits : PRD_ID
Ligne Commande : LGCM_CMD_ID, LGCM_PRD_ID

CMD_ID = LGCM_CMD_ID
LGCM_PRD_ID = PRD_ID
```

i'm getting this result :

```
(29) - 028001 - AC 1ERES C.DE BLAYE. CH L.BERTRANDS     1   

(30) - 028001 - AC 1ERES C.DE BLAYE. CH L.BERTRANDS     7   

(31) - 028001 - AC 1ERES C.DE BLAYE. CH L.BERTRANDS     7
```

I want to show only the last LGCM_ID , i tried to use MAX (LGCM_ID) but when i used it, 
i got `(31) - 028001 - AC 1ERES C.DE BLAYE. CH L.BERTRANDS` but the value 1 not 7 for the quantity ordered... (LGCM_QTE_COMMANDE)

I need that because i want to show the products that the consummer has already ordered before.

```
<?php

foreach ($query=$db->query("SELECT
t1.CMD_ID, CMD_DATE, t1.CMD_CLT_ID,
MAX(t2.LGCM_ID) AS LGCM_LAST_ID, t2.LGCM_CMD_ID, t2.LGCM_PRD_ID, t2.LGCM_QTE_COMMANDE,
t3.PRD_ID, t3.PRD_CODE, t3.PRD_LIBELLE
FROM commandes t1
INNER JOIN ligne_commande t2
ON t1.CMD_ID = t2.LGCM_CMD_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN produits t3
ON t2.LGCM_PRD_ID = t3.PRD_ID WHERE t1.CMD_CLT_ID = 418") AS $donnees):

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>('.$donnees['LGCM_LAST_ID'].') - '.$donnees['PRD_CODE'].' - '.$donnees['PRD_LIBELLE'].'</td>';
echo '<td>/</td>';
echo '<td>'.$donnees['LGCM_QTE_COMMANDE'].'</td>';
echo '<td>/</td>';
echo '</tr>';

endforeach;

?>
```

Thanks.

EDIT : 
Look this picture :

[image: http://nsa34.casimages.com/img/2014/01/03//140103055118239421.jpg]

I want to show only the number 38, 37, 36.
It's the last product that the consummer ordered.

Comment: So it sounds like what you really want is to show a list of distinct products the person has ordered.  Why do you need the `LGCM` at all?  Are you trying to just show a distinct list, or are you trying to list them and also link to when they last ordered that product?

Comment: hey, i need LGCM because the quantity is stocked in this table (LGCM_QTE_COMMANDE). CMD is for the TOTAL (each LGCM cumulate) and CMD is linked to a consummer (CMD_CLT_ID). Yes i'm trying to list them and also link to when they last ordered that product.

Comment: I modified my answer.  That should get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just `ORDER BY` your `LGCM_ID DESC` and limit your results to 1 record, which in mysql is `LIMIT 1`

Since I don't have your original query that returns 3 records, I can only give you the above recommendation.  But use that query with those two additions that I specified and you should be good to go.

EDIT: The question has been updated.  So what you really want to do is get the last order id for each product ordered by a particular customer.

To do that, see this [JS Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70ff1/4)

```
SELECT cp.*, p.Name
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN Customer_Products cp ON cp.P_ID = p.ID
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT MAX(cp.ID) AS Max_ID
  FROM Customer_Products cp
  WHERE cp.C_ID = 1
  GROUP BY cp.P_ID)
AS t0 ON t0.Max_ID = cp.ID;
```

The `t0` INNER JOIN gets you the maximum `ID` of the order for each product ordered by a customer, which is achieved through the `GROUP BY cp.P_ID` statement.  Then, given that max id, we join back to the `Customer_Products` to get details from that order, such as the QTY ordered.  And working up one more level, we join to `Products` so we can get the product name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
It's working if there is only one product (with the same id) ordered by the consummer.

But i tried to order with a test account, other products several times and it's not showing the other result. Only one because of the limit...

Comment: I suggest you update your question to give more information about truly what you're trying to do because I did not follow your explanation just now.  From your original question, it looked like you wanted just the max id -- i.e. the last record -- to be returned.  If that's not the case, then what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok guys, i edited my post, i illustrated it with a picture. thanks